# How to read file lines structure exactly as they appear in Android?

Tags: android, text, file-read

So I want to read a text file in Android. I don't stuck in the general procedure of *"how to read a file"* but how to **view** the contents of it in an *(multiline)*`EditText` exactly as they appear?

For example, the structure of a file is like that:

[image: Structured file]

How to view the file that way, and not that way:

[image: Non-Structured file]

What class should I use, and what delimiters if needed to proceed?

Apart from the explanation, any example will be appreciated in advance!

Comment: `and not that way:`. What did you do to see it that way on one line?

Comment: Reading it through a BufferReader?

Comment: Does such reading make text visible? How did you make it visible is the question you should answer.

Comment: I print it out in an EditText of course..

Comment: You think it's clever not to show the code you use?